# How to continue in Jmeter, as if the http response is received correctly for an http request?

Tags: jmeter

There is an http request that the server is not responding it with an "http or http/json response".
The server sends some **tcp** messages like [ACK] and [PSH,ACK].

But JMeter waits for an **http response**, because the request is http request sampler.

Is there a proper way that i can continue as if the response of this request is received correctly?

[image: sample result :]

[image: response data]

[image: response body]

[image]

Comment: Can you include the sample screenshot of the `Sampler Result` and `Response Data --> Body and Header ` from the view result tree?

Comment: i include the screenshots. in this test, there is a response timeout value for signalr/connect request (10ms). so the response body is related to this timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I am I correct in saying you're more looking for a TCP sampler rather than a HTTP sample?

Comment: i have to send the request with http protocol.

Comment: Ok cool so you need to send HTTP but get back TCP responses? If so you could set a JSR Post Processor to have prev.setSuccessful(true) which would cause JMETER's HTTP sampler to "fire and forget"

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what I posted above will work for you. Give it a try though. Failing that, you could write all your HTTP requests in a beanshell sampler and don't wait for the response?

Comment: i will try beanshell. the other related with jsr post processor didnt work. when adding it, the result of the request has passed (turned green) but, jmeter ends the communication sending fin tcp request.

Comment: any sample http get request by using beanshell?

Answer (score 0):

TCP ACK is not response which you want I guess. It's just transport layer acknowledge. According to HTTP protocol there should be response for every request, I mean HTTP response. So your server doesn't work correctly and jMeter shows it.

Comment: there is also a [PSH,ACK] response message. when i perform the test with browser, it goes on without any problem. but your answer makes sense. is it an obligation to respond with http protocol for all signalr requests. if yes, the server doesnt work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the requests which JMeter sends with the requests the real browser sends, configure JMeter to behave exactly like the real browser and that would be it.

If you want a comprehensive answer you need to show:

1. Full HTTP Request details in Wireshark (like [Follow HTTP Stream](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowStreamSection.html)) from the real browser
2. The same for JMeter
3. Your HTTP Request sampler configuration (including any configuration elements involved like [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager))

---

Blind shot: can it be the case that your HTTP Request sampler invokes [switching protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/101) and later communication happens using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)?

If yes - double check that you're sending proper headers like:

- [Connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection): [Upgrade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade)
- Upgrade: websocket

and once done continue simulating the traffic using [WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

Comment: note : i want to add .jmx file here.                                                                                              i investigated the differences between chrome and jmeter carefully, the only difference is to manage the tcp responses. jmeter cant manage to receive tcp response to a http request. i look at that issue when i running from browser. the server does not respond with an http or http/json to signalr/connect request. this is the issue. browser understands but jmeter doesnt.

Comment: server selects the transport method as "serverSentEvents". and whole the test this transport method is used, valid for both browser and jmeter

Comment: JMeter's HTTP Request samplers don't support "serverSentEvents", if you need to fetch some information from them i.e. for [correlation purposes](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) you will need to use a special library from JSR223 Test Elements like it's described in [How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-sse-services-with-jmeter) article

Comment: i am going to try this tomorrow. but i have already overcome the correlation issue (connectionToken). because the other signalr requests, from than signalr/connect, have http responses sent by server.